# Custom Title bar with Holo Themes

Tags: android, android-theme, custom-titlebar

Like a lot of people, I would like to use a custom title bar in android but also use the Holo theme. I've seen a lot of posts recommending using `Theme.Holo.NoActionBar` but it still gives me the same error as when I change my custom theme to use `Theme.Holo`. I want to resolve once and for all, is it possible to use a custom title bar like this:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.custom_title_bar);
```

which seems to be the most common way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can create another element layout which looks like title bar for you and in the current activity you can set `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)`

This way you get the holo theme aswell as custom title. This is commonly used practice in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seems to be the only way of making it work bit it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

you can define `parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo"` 
then just disable the windows action bar

like this

```
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
```

in theme.

It's working for me...